# Confused by "Scala in Depth" Option example

Tags: java, scala, type-inference, scala-option

Chapter 2 of the new Manning book, "Scala in Depth" by Josh Sueresh is posted [here](http://java.dzone.com/news/free-chapter-scala-depth-using). In reading the article, I came across this bit of code:

```
def getTemporaryDirectory(tmpArg : Option[String]) : java.io.File = {

   tmpArg.map(name => new java.io.File(name)).

          filter(_.isDirectory).

       getOrElse(new java.io.File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")))

}
```

The follow up text explaining the above code read:

> The getTemporaryDirectory method takes the command line parameter as
>   an Option containing a String and returns a File object referencing
>   the temporary directory we should use. The first thing we do is use
>   the map method on Option to create a java.io.File  if there was a
>   parameter. Next, we make sure that this newly constructed file object
>   is a directory. To do that, we use the filter  method. This will check
>   whether the value in an Option abides by some predicate and, if not,
>   convert to a None. Finally, we check to see if we have a value in the
>   Option; otherwise, we return the default temporary directory.

So, for me coming from Java and learning Scala, the code syntax confuses me. I don't get how there is a dot following the map(...) function call. It appears there is so much type inference occurring, I am missing something somewhere and not seeing the types.

It would be very helpful to me, learning Scala, to be able to somehow see all the inferred types, to uninfer (or unapply) all the reductions, i.e. the over-verbose version that looks something like pre-Java 6 where the types had to be explict on both sides of the equals for collection classes.

Is there a tool anywhere that would take a Scala code snippet and make explicit different things (perhaps as flags; one for types, another for implicits, another for braces, another for semicolons). I just need something to walk me from completely terse code to something closer to Java so I can feel confident building my skill at reading (and eventually writing) more terse Scala.

Here's kind of what I am looking for:

```
def getTemporaryDirectory(tmpArg : Option[String]) : java.io.File = {

   ContainerType1[Type1] t1 = tmpArg.map(name => new java.io.File(name));
   ContainerType2[Type2] t2 = t1.filter(_.isDirectory);
   return t2.getOrElse(new java.io.File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));

}
```

I am not stuck on the above specifically. I just am unable to follow how the the chained function calls work in terms of what's actually happening due to type inference. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This article makes a point similar to the challenge I am experiencing above: http://zeroturnaround.com/blog/scala-sink-or-swim-part-1/

Comment: At this level, you'll benefit more from Odersky et al's Programming in Scala than from Suereth's Scala in Depth. Just saying.

Comment: [This post](http://skipoleschris.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/map-flatten-and-flatmap.html) and nice animation will possibly give you a more sence

Comment: @Daniel Per your suggestion, I am now re-reading Odersky's book (2nd edition). It's turned out to be an excellent suggestion for me. I got so much out of it the first time. And now re-reading it a year later, I am seeing how much I missed the first time through. And I am now using REPL to play with the examples in the book as I proceed. I think I need to actually "play" in REPL to grok some of the more "abstract" things that I am not going to get just "reading". Thank goodness for e-readers. I have it on my phone, on my laptop, on my tablet and on my work computer. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, you do have the REPL to try the chained commands one by one and check their result types, but I'm not sure seeing the signatures will help you so much:

```
scala> Some("c:\\users\\paolo")
res0: Some[java.lang.String] = Some(c:\users\paolo)

scala> res0.map(name => new java.io.File(name))
res1: Option[java.io.File] = Some(c:\users\paolo)

scala> res1.filter(_.isDirectory)
res2: Option[java.io.File] = Some(c:\users\paolo)

scala> res2.getOrElse(new java.io.File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")))
res3: java.io.File = c:\users\paolo
```

Now let's try it again, starting with None.

```
scala> None:Option[String]
res6: Option[String] = None

scala> res6.map(name => new java.io.File(name))
res7: Option[java.io.File] = None

scala> res7.filter(_.isDirectory)
res8: Option[java.io.File] = None

scala> res8.getOrElse(new java.io.File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")))
res9: java.io.File = C:\Users\paolo\AppData\Local\Temp
```

So using `Option` helped us "propagate" the `None` without checking for nulls at every step like we would probably do in java.

As you see there's not a lot of type inference happening here.
I think the root of your confusion may be that `map` and `filter` (among others) are usually associated to collections of some kind, so it may be hard to grok what they do on Option, which is only remotely similar to a collection.
For that I refer you to the classic [scala.Option cheat sheet](http://blog.tmorris.net/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/)

Comment: In the third line of "scala> res0.map(name => new java.io.File(name))", where did the variable name come from? I'm guessing that should be res0, right?

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium the scala REPL creates automatically a val to assign the value of each expression you type in, and it names them res0, res1, res2 and so on. In the first line I've typed `Some("c:\\users\\paolo")`, so scala automatically interpreted this as `val res0 = Some("c:\\users\\paolo")` and replied that `res0` has type `Some[java.lang.String]` and value `Some(c:\users\paolo)`. Then I used `map` on `res0`, which in turn returned a `res1` with type `Option[java.io.File]` and value `Some(c:\users\paolo)`... and so on

Comment: Nevermind, I re-read it and now get the res0.map and that name is the parameter name for the map function.

Comment: @Paulo Thank you for doing it with REPL. I really appreciate that. It's a great way to figure out how to tear apart the method/function. I will do that in the future.

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium: oh, yes, sorry... I had not gotten your question.

Answer (score 2):

The trailing dot is simply chained to the method `filter` on the next line. There's no inference at play.

This can be re-written as

```
import java.io._

def getTemporaryDirectory(tmpArg : Option[String]) : File = {
    tmpArg.map(name => new File(name)).filter(_.isDirectory).getOrElse(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")))
}
```

Comment: That's not what I meant. I get that it is a series of method calls. What I am not getting is what type is being returned upon which the next method is called. The type inference is hiding (from my unexperienced eyes) what type is being returned by each function.

Comment: @chaotic - But there is no real type inference necessarily going in this example, except for types of the functions that are used as method arguments. Java version with chained calls would look exactly like `return tmpArg.map(...).filter(...).getOrElse(new File())` only the `...` would have to be some terrible function object instantiations.

Comment: @Michal I get that I could do that in Java. However, in general I know most of the activities that can occur in a Java sequence like that. There's all sorts of things in Scala I don't understand which is reducing my confidence in reading and understanding the sequence. My gap was that filter() returned an Option[File] which the last dot was then using.

Comment: Actually there **is** inference: you don't have to write `map(name: String => ....)` instead you writing `map(name => ...)`

Answer (score 1):

To be explicit:

```
def getTemporaryDirectory(tmpArg : Option[String]) : java.io.File = {
  val v1: Option[java.io.File] = tmpArg.map(name => new java.io.File(name))
  val v2: Option[java.io.File] = v1.filter(_.isDirectory)
  val v3: File = v2.getOrElse(new java.io.File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")))
}
```

There's still a lot of type inference going on here, and Daniel Spiewak has [an excellent presentation on type inference](http://screencasts.chariotsolutions.com/uncovering-the-unknown-principles-of-type-inference-). It really gives you a sense of what types Scala is capable of inferring.

More specifically on this example.

`Option[A]`'s `map` method has the signature `map[B](f: A => B): Option[B]`. Since `tmpArg` is `Option[String]`, the compiler knows that the type of the parameter is `String => B`. Now it can infer that `name` is `String`. Inspecting the function, it can see that the function returns a `File`. Now the compiler can infer that the type of the parameter is `String => File`, and that this `map` invocation returns `Option[File]`.

`Option[A]`'s `filter` method has the signature `filter (p: A => Boolean): Option[A]`. The function literal `_.isDirectory` is simply a shorthand for `x => x.isDirectory`. Given that `A` is now `File`, the compiler can infer that `_` is also `File`. And the result is `Option[File]`.

Finally, we have `Option[A]`'s `getOrElse` method, with the signature `getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): B`. The syntax `B >: A` specifies a type parameter `B` constrained to be the same or super type as `A`. The syntax `=> B` specifies the parameter as a by-name/lazy parameter, which is only evaluated if needed. The parameter passed in is of type `File`, meaning that `B` is `File`, and this `getOrElse` returns `File`.

Comment: That's what I was looking for in the specific problem. So, .map and .filter both return Option[File]. Any ideas on a tool I can use to "unterse" a snippet of Scala code like this so I can learn all the key points to begin inferring the types myself?

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium if you hover over the terms in Eclipse, it tells you their types.

Comment: Awesome! I'll try that, too, ASAP. Tyvm.

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium I added some more info that will hopefully help you get the hang of inference. I highly recommend watching Daniel's presentation; it's very informative.

Comment: @dave I have now watched Daniel's presentation. Tyvm for posting a link to it. While some of it went over my head, what I did understand helped me to grok just a bit deeper into Scala and reflection.

Answer (score 1):

An additional resource, along with the REPL, is to use your IDE to decompose and / or annotate chained expressions.

For example in IntelliJ I can hover over a method call and see it's type signature and if I have the source available I can click through and see the implementation.

However restating Daniel's advice, a book like Programming in Scala would be a much easier starting point, covering type inference and also the syntax rules of the language (which might be contributing more to the confusion in this example).

Comment: I've been using the Eclipse IDE. However, I had not noticed it revealed types when hovering over a snippet of code. That's very helpful.